# WICD DNS not working

Tags: networking, dns, wicd

Heads up: I am a networking noob and have little idea of what I am doing.

I switched to a different wm and therefore, Ubuntu's default network manager became cumbersome, so I installed wicd in hopes that it would be a more elegant solution. Unfortunatley, DNS is being somewhat problematic.

I can connect to my router and ping the 8.8.8.8 dns server, so I know I have a connection to the internet. However, I cannot navigate to webpages from a browser.

In wicd, there are options for me to set Global DNS Servers. The options are as follows.

```
DNS domain
Search domain
DNS server 1
DNS server 2
DNS server 3
```

I can display any other files needed to troubleshoot this problem. Please send help.

Comment: You can edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add : `nameserver 8.8.8.8` `nameserver 8.8.4.4 ` This will add Google's nameservers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the permanent solution, I recommend you to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`
And add the following:

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
       dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
       dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4
```

(Replace `wlan0` with your network interface, you can check the name via:
**ip address show**)
After then `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`